# vue.js integrate remote script with callback into vue into

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning vue.js and struggling to understand the vue 'way' to integrate with a remote script.  Case in point, loading a [google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) map into an element.

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

I've no doubt I could fudge something together but would be curious to know best practice in this situation.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: See https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-maps

Comment: nice thanks.  had presumed vue was to small to have packages like this.  Interesting to see how they implemented this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Vue.js Map component.

First, make sure you have a main Vue instance for your app:

```
var myApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

Then you can create your map component:

```
Vue.component('map', {
    template: '#myMap',
    data: function () {
  data: {
    map: null;
  },
  methods: {
    initMap: function() {
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Here is an example using Vue loader:
https://github.com/crabbly/vue-google-maps-example

If you want to use Vue loader (write components in one file):
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader